# “Two teachers are the same person.”

Tags: definite-article

“A teacher you’ve met on Monday and a teacher you’ve met on Friday are the same person.”

It means two teachers you’ve met on Monday and Friday are the same person.

I wonder if the latter “a” should be changed into “the” because they indicate the same person.

Should it be “a teacher you’ve met on Monday and **the** teacher you’ve met on Friday are the same person”?

Comment: “**The** teacher you’ve met on Monday and **the** teacher you’ve met on Friday are the same person”

Comment: @myacorn I searched a little bit. But English speakers say it’s the same person, not they are the same person. Is it right?

Comment: **A** teacher just means "one of many possible teachers".  If you met multiple teachers on Monday and multiple teachers on Friday, but the speaker is only talking about one of them, it could be natural to say **a** in both cases.  I would expect "A teacher you’ve met on Monday and a teacher you’ve met on Friday are the same person" to be followed by something like "Can you guess who it was?"

Comment: By the way, it would be much more natural to say "A teacher you **met** on Monday/Friday", because the meeting is a single event that was completed in the past, so the simple past tense is the natural choice.

Answer (score 4):

"The" and "the" would be natural.

The set up is rather odd.  You talk about "the two teachers", but there is only one teacher.  There were two meetings, but *one* teacher.  And, of course, why would you need to explain that "the one teacher was one teacher".  If the teacher had been wearing a disguise... perhaps - but this is odd.

However, instances of the word "teacher" are completely determined in the mind of the speaker by the phrase "[that] you met on Monday", (or Friday) and so "the" should be used for both.

> Did you realise that the teacher you met on Friday was the same as the teacher on Monday? He'd cut his hair and shaved his beard, so he looked completely different.

Unless, of course you mean "one of the teachers that you met on Friday", for which you could say "a teacher"  But this context is getting less and less practical.  There are much more natural ways to express this:

> You met Mr Smith on Friday, but you'd already met him on Monday.